# X11 app-defaults file in binary format?

Tags: xorg

I have been trying to modify the default background color for an X11 application, and the instructions are to edit its app-defaults file. In my past experience, these have been easily modifiable text files. But for one particular application, my app-defaults file appears to be in some sort of binary format. Is this normal, and how can I modify this file?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just corrupted?

Comment: It could be, I don't know. Are they always text files?

Comment: What does the `file` command output when run on the app-defaults file?

Comment: @grawity: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application default files are always text. There is no such thing as binary application default files. In fact, files like `~/.Xdefaults` which are processed with `xrdb` must be suitable as input to a C preprocessor. If your file looks like a binary file it probably got overwritten with binary content somehow. Just restore it from your backups :-)

Comment: Yeah, I just ended up deleting the file and making a new one. Thanks for looking into this necro thread though, I'll give you credit for it :).